# Can proving an implication where the antecedent is false be useful?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Say one proved that A --> B, but later A was found to be false. Could this still be useful? My thinking is that it could maybe be used in a separate proof by contradiction/contrapositive.

Comment: Well, of course the ideas you used in the proof might be useful.  But, logically, a false statement implies any statement so there's no benefit from that.

Comment: @lulu ah right, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't tell us anything about $B$. It's not interesting.

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by $A$ being false.  If $A$ is false in every model, then the implication is useless.  If $A$ is true in some model in which your proof of $A\to B$ still works, then it could still have some utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lulu just pointed out, a false antecedent implies any statement. So the final fact alone of "A --> B" wouldn't be useful.